# ImportError: cannot import name 'Adadelta' from 'keras.optimizers'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, objective-c-runtime

ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
`from bidaf.models import BidirectionalAttentionFlow`
`bidaf_model = BidirectionalAttentionFlow(400)`
`keras_model = bidaf_model.model`

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\bidaf\models_init_.py in
`from bidaf.models import BidirectionalAttentionFlow`

**~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\bidaf\models\bidaf.py in**

**ImportError: cannot import name 'Adadelta' from 'keras.optimizers' (C:\Users\vishd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py)**

I have been trying to recreate the Keras-bidaf model in my python notebook and running this code in python from bidaf. models import BidirectionalAttentionFlow which keeps giving me the above error and saying Adadelta can't be imported from Keras. I have tried so many options to solve it but no luck.

I am stuck here. Any suggestions and ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: @TFer2                                                                                                                         
Thanks. Here's my google colab notebook where I have tried to recreate the bidaf-model                       https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zZySISeilQpkeTFrYve79zicB-LH_9FU